# Error: Missing '<EOF>' at 'public' --- > Wrapper class in VFP (pls help)

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

Apex:

```java
public with sharing class WrapperClassTrainingDealApex {
    
    public Training_Deal__c Tdeal {set; get;}
    public Trainer_Master__c Tmaster {set; get;}
  
    //contructor class for property to Object Initialisation
    
    public WrapperClassTrainingDealApex (Training_Deal__c TD, Trainer_Master__c TM){
        
        Tdeal = TD;
        Tmaster = TM;
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyController{
        
    public list<WrapperClassTrainingDealApex> WrapperList{set; get;}

    //contructor class for property to Object Initialisation
    public MyController(){
            
        WrapperList = new list<WrapperClassTrainingDealApex>();
       
        List<Training_Deal__c> TraningDeal = [SELECT Name, Course__c FROM Training_Deal__c LIMIT 10];
        List<Trainer_Master__c> TraningMaster = [SELECT Name, Last_Name__c, Education__c FROM Trainer_Master__c LIMIT 10];
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
            WrapperClassTrainingDealApex wrapper = new WrapperClassTrainingDealApex (TraningDeal[i], TraningMaster[i]);
            WrapperList.add(wrapper);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the formatting here to be more standard/consistent. I'm assuming that these two classes are in two separate files. If you actually have these two classes in a _single_ file, then that's your problem. Apex can only have one top-level class per file.

Comment: Thank you very much.....  issue resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Apex only allows a single top-level class in a single file.

You need to either split this into two separate files, or make the wrapper class be an *inner class*.

E.g.

```java
public class MyController{
    public list<WrapperClassTrainingDealApex> WrapperList{set; get;}

    // We can declare a class inside of another class
    // This is an "inner" class
    // You can have multiple inner classes, but you cannot have an inner class
    //   inside of an inner class
    public class WrapperClassTrainingDealApex {
        public Training_Deal__c Tdeal {set; get;}
        public Trainer_Master__c Tmaster {set; get;}
    
        public WrapperClassTrainingDealApex (Training_Deal__c TD, Trainer_Master__c TM){
            Tdeal = TD;
            Tmaster = TM;
        }
    }

    public MyController(){
        // Inner classes can be referenced by their name (just like any other class)
        //   inside of the "outer" class.
        // In other classes though, you'd need to use <outer>.<inner> to reference it
        //   e.g. List<MyController.WrapperClassTrainingDealApex>
        WrapperList = new List<WrapperClassTrainingDealApex>();
       
        List<Training_Deal__c> TraningDeal = [SELECT Name, Course__c FROM Training_Deal__c LIMIT 10];
        List<Trainer_Master__c> TraningMaster = [SELECT Name, Last_Name__c, Education__c FROM Trainer_Master__c LIMIT 10];
        
        for(Integer i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
            WrapperClassTrainingDealApex wrapper = new WrapperClassTrainingDealApex (TraningDeal[i], TraningMaster[i]);
            WrapperList.add(wrapper);
        }
    }
}
```